# Only one value? SQL Connect - Wiki Markup

Tags: php, sql, text, wiki, markup

actual im working on a wiki project to get db datas by markups with db connection.

my problem is:

the frontend only shows the last line "of data / $text"
$text = $zeile['name'];

all other (here e.g. 
$text = $zeile['largeimage'];`
$text = $zeile['link'];) are not shown in the front -

no error - just not shown :(

my code is:

```
Markup_e('amazon','inline',"/\\[:amazon ([A-Z;,a-z,0-9,' ']+):\\]/",
"PRR().amazon(\$m[1])");

function Amazon($name) {

    include('/www/htdocs/drtaarde/inc/config.php'); //Datenbankverbindung herstellen

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM d029a62b WHERE asin LIKE '%$name%';";

    $db_erg = mysqli_query( $link, $sql );
    if ( ! $db_erg ) {
        die('Ungültige Abfrage: ' . mysqli_error());
    }

    while ($zeile = mysqli_fetch_array( $db_erg, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

        $text = $zeile['largeimage'];
        $text = $zeile['link'];
        $text = $zeile['name'];


        return $text; 
    }
}
```

thanks for any reply

Answer (score 0):

Your overwrite `$test` variable and just store the last data `name`:

```
$text = $zeile['largeimage'];
$text = $zeile['link'];
$text = $zeile['name'];
```

So, you finally store in `$text` the value in `$zeile['name']`.

If you want just return those 3 values, you could, for instance, create an associative array with just those 3 values and return it, something like;

```
return [
    'largeimage' => $zeile['largeimage'],
    'link' => $zeile['link'],
    'name' => $zeile['name']
];
```

and then processed as you want.

Besides, your return the value inside of the while loop: you function should return it after processing all data:

```
function Amazon($name) {

    include('/www/htdocs/drtaarde/inc/config.php'); //Datenbankverbindung herstellen

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM d029a62b WHERE asin LIKE '%$name%';";
    $db_erg = mysqli_query( $link, $sql );

    if ( ! $db_erg ) {
        die('Ungültige Abfrage: ' . mysqli_error());
    }

    $response = [];
    while ($zeile = mysqli_fetch_array( $db_erg, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $response[] = [
            'largeimage' => $zeile['largeimage'],
            'link' => $zeile['link'],
            'name' => $zeile['name']
        ];  
    }

    return $response;
}
```

**Update**
Probably it doesn't work because now `Amazon` function returns an array, and before a string, so you can encode the array to JSON, so you will receive a string as JSON like `[{"largeimage":"largeimagevalue1","link":"linkvalue1","name":"namevalue1"},{"largeimage":"largeimagevalue2","link":"linkvalue2","name":"namevalue2"}]`so you have to return something like:

```
return json_encode($response);
```